# link to CSS stylesheet

Tags: php, css, wordpress, stylesheet

I have a option in my Wordpress theme options panel that I made to choose from five different styles. Running Wordpress on localhost if I choose yellow, red, green, blue or black the style is applied correctly and everything works fine. The code I'm using in `header.php` is this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/<?php echo get_option('of_cssstyles'); ?>.css" />
```

But when I install the same theme on the web I get a webpage with absolutly no CSS style, you can see it here: (http://macoverflow.org/p3dra/), as you can see no CSS style is beeing applied.

How to fix this?

Comment: First, verify that the output from PHP is generating the expected URL for the stylesheet. The page you link to does not have a stylesheet located at the `href` from the `link` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stylesheet you are linking to doesn't exist. You need to upload it to the server or link to somewhere it is uploaded.

edit: going to: http://macoverflow.org/p3dra/wp-content/themes/blankfolio/css/ shows that the stylesheet is actually called "yellow.css", but the page you are linking to is "Yellow.css" note the case of the "y".

Comment: I reuploaded my theme and activated it. Without changing any code now some styling is showing. Maybe is a permissions problem. I changed the y to Y but still does not work! But on localhost works fine.

Comment: @RicardoRibeiro, Yellow.css doesn't exist. You either need to upload the css as "Yellow.css" or change the php to return "yellow.css"

Comment: it does exist, I confirmed with ftp, all files are there. When I try and edit with firebug it doesn´t find it. only style.css. But all files are there inside the css folder.

Comment: @RicardoRibeiro, Your site looks fine now, whatever you did.

Comment: I copied all the files in css folder to the styles folder, and it worked. But now I cannot change any style from the theme options panel. This is a bit confusing because I link the css files to the css folder NOT the styles folder wich I dont even need. Maybe there´s some php function linking also to the styles folder.

Comment: All working fine now! Thanks a lot. I just remove the php code wich was overriding my css folder. And changing the first letter of the css files was important also.

Comment: @RicardoRibeiro, no problem, I'm glad everything is working !

Answer (score 0):

Did you upload your stylesheets to the server?
Did you set the permissions on the stylesheet to be readable by apache?
I received the following by looking at the final html codein the finished page:

http://macoverflow.org/p3dra/wp-content/themes/blankfolio/css/Yellow.css

This is not found.

Comment: I reuploaded my theme and activated it. Without changing any code now some styling is showing. Maybe is a permissions problem.

Answer (score -1):

whats he is saying is the file name is caase sensitive so Yellow.css and yellow.css are two different files in the eyes of the apache, they are as different as having one called yellow.css and he other called pink.css , the detail is in the first letter, being a capital.

Comment: I understand that and I already made the changes for that to work, but still i´m having problems.

Comment: who the hell's down voted me for this, I made the comment before the answer was edited.